# InternalServerError when calling the synchronization API's

Tags: azure-active-directory, synchronization, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to automate the process of updating admin credentials inside an enterprise app in AAD. Looking at the Microsoft docs e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-provisioning-configure-api?tabs=http) this should be possible via the graph api. Whenever I attempt these steps I'm running into "InternalServerError" along with "Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: UnknownError".

My dotnet code for validating existing credentials is the following.

```
await graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals[$"{servicePrincipalId}"].Synchronization.Jobs[$"{jobsId}"]
                .ValidateCredentials(null,null,null,credentials)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
```

The result is the error above with the same error for any other synchonization method. I've considered it could be a permissions issue but I've found that the api does a reasonable job of sending permission issues back so I'm stumped at this point.

Does anybody have any advice on this?

Comment: (1) Share the response logs (with timestamp, requestid). (2) What if you do retry or retry after sometime? Does it helped?

Comment: date: 2020-12-01T19:29:23, request-id: 6ce859dc-00e2-4981-9559-15e12bb22651, client-request-id: 6ce859dc-00e2-4981-9559-15e12bb22651. I haven't managed to do this successfully at all so far.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if you try the same API call in Microsoft Graph Explorer (outside of your application)?

Comment: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/synchronization/jobs returns UnknownError on Graph Explorer.

Comment: I see that you're shared this "The result is the error above with the same error for any other synchonization method". I would do the basic sanity checks (1) Validate the credentials that you're using; make sure the user context has necessary scopes/roles defined too (2) Make sure the template and the parameters that you're is correct.

Comment: Do you have Directory.ReadWrite.All delegated permissions? Is your account a work or school account? Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots

Comment: What value did you set in request body for this call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-provisioning-configure-api?tabs=http#test-the-connection-to-the-application? Where did you get the `ClientSecret` and `SecretToken`?

Comment: It's working in graph explorer now; the problem was I hadn't assigned an app role to the user I was using for delegating permissions. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: Gotcha. Glad to hear that @theor. Thanks for confirming and it aligns with the basic sanity checks that i shared above.

Comment: I will move this to answer. Consider upvoting it; so it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're updated that "The result is the error above with the same error for any other synchronization method".  In such scenario, I would do the basic sanity checks

- Validate the credentials that
  you're using
- Make sure the user context has necessary scopes/roles
  defined too
- Make sure the template and the parameters that you're
  is correct.
- Once you assigned app role to the user that you're using for delegating permissions, it worked for you.